# Do the following ACF and PACF plots show a ARIMA(1,0,0) model?

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

I am trying to find the correct ARIMA model for a time series without seasonality that produce the following ACF and PACF plots.[image]

Looking at these plots my initial hypothesis is that an ARIMA(1,0,0) model is required due to the PACF dropping to 0 after lag 1, but the ACF is decaying too slowly for me to be sure about it.

Comment: My guess would be (0,1,0) BUT only your data knows for sure as the apparent ACF could reflect latent deterministic structure . Post your actual data and I will try and help further.

Comment: My data is the monthly Disney stock prices taken from [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DIS/history?period1=-252374400&period2=1578960000&interval=1mo&filter=history&frequency=1mo)

Comment: most probably (0,1,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most probably (0,1,0) as  stock prices are usually random walk models.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for your help!